# Xcode Playground Failed to launch

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-m1

I can't run any Xcode Swift Playground project without getting the error:

> Failed to launch process. Failed to attach to stub for playground execution: error: attach failed ((os/kern) invalid argument)

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: PSA: Please stop adding answers that are just variants of how to get to the Rosetta setting to turn it off.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I've the same issue. If I launch Xcode using rosetta, it doesn't show anything. You must switch off rosetta and it works perfect.

Comment: are there any other solution, i way to lazy switching from rosetta and not everything I switch from muy prod app and personal app/exercise

Comment: @Farhandika yes, you can have multiple Xcodes. They may even be the same version of Xcode. Just rename the binary.

Download from developer.apple.com and not the app store.

Answer (score 23):

To expand on @E.P's answer

To put off rosetta Go to Aplications-->Xcode-->Get info --> Uncheck rosetta.
You need to restart the system in some cases

Answer (score 3):

Right click on Xcode, Get Info, Uncheck Rosetta. Then quit Xcode from Dock and re open your playground file.

[image: UncheckRosetta]